# How can you get rolling value count (frequency) with Pandas? (computationally efficient, no loops)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have a list of values and I want to get their rolling frequency, so something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'val': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
})

result = df.val.rolling(3).freq()

result == pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

Of course I can do this with a loop but with a lot of data it can be computationally expensive so I'd much rather use a built-in or something vectorized, etc. But unfortunately, from my searching, there doesn't seem to be a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does it contradict it? And the first one.

Comment: how can the first two elements of a result of a rolling function with a window size of 3 be different from `NaN` as in your desired output?

Comment: @Mr.T `[1, 1, 2]` returns `1` because `2` only appears once in the window (assuming T-2, T-1, T0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `n-1` elements of the result of a rolling function with window size `n` must be `NaN` per definition.

```
result = df.val.rolling(3).apply(lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x==x.iloc[-1])).astype('Int64')
```

Result:

```
0     <NA>
1     <NA>
2        3
3        3
4        3
5        1
6        2
7        3
8        3
9        3
10       1
11       2
12       3
13       3
14       3
```

Comment: Not exactly, I know I put a number as the window but I'll actually be using this for time-series and if you put a window in string representation then it doesn't fill incomplete windows with `NaN`s -- nevertheless, this is a great solution and it beat mine by ~50% so thank you!!